# Npm publish returns write EPIPE Error in GCP

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, repository, publish, artifact

I am trying to publish a NodeJS package to a private repository in GCP, configurating the .npmrc files and authentication with this quickstart: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/quickstart, and when I try to publish it through the command line it returns me the error:

```
verbose stack FetchError: request to https://myurl-gcp/myproject/myrepo/@scope%2fmypackage failed, reason: write EPIPE
verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:110:14)
verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:378:20)
verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

If I try to package the project it works, and if I use it in another project as imported module it also works.

Version NPM: 7.20.5
Verison Node: 15.11.0

Any doubts why it is happening?

Comment: Have you tried `npm login` first ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

I was missing the `files` property in the `package.json` of the package.

Also I was having problems because I am using a corporate proxy and the package had around 20 MB, so deleting also the bundled dependencies it works!